# Vue: how to define the if condition in my case

Tags: vue.js

I am currently working on a project facing below problem,

```
<img v-if="blog.thumbnail" :src='backendurl+blog.thumbnail.url'>
```

I would like to get the correct url from database if the thumbnail.url exist. Below is my json get from API for blog.thumbnail.url and also source code inspection.

I can see all the blog runs the :src='backendurl+blog.thumbnail.url' and the v-if is not working?
How to fix it if I want only run this code with vaild thumbnail.url?

Thanks

Stan

[Json from API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVUEZ.png)

[Source code Inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QWq8.png)

Comment: from you screenshort what I can see, blog.thumbnail is an array.  So I am guessing you should try like this, `v-if="blog.thumbnail[index].url"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div v-for="(blog, n) in blogs" :key="n">
    <img v-if="blog.thumbnail.length" :src="blog.thumbnail[0].url" alt="thumbnail" />

    <h1>{{ blog.title }}</h1>

    <div v-html="blog.content"></div>
</div>
```

If that doesn't work, just write {{ blog }} and see what it displays, then write {{ blog.thumbnail }} to see what you get there. This way you can get to the right syntax step by step.

You don't need the backend url if it's on the same server, else backendurl + blog.thumbnail[0].url should work.